# Identify and change extreme datetime outliers within a group

Tags: python, pandas

I have a slice of a dataframe that identifies devices that did not disconnect at the same time as everybody else (basically, people who forget to hang up).  I have sorted this slice by UniqueCallID and LeaveTime so that the outlier is always the last one in the conference "group" and I want to change that outlier's LeaveTime to be the LeaveTime of the one before it, if the difference is more than x amount of time (60 minutes or 1 hour).

I've tried grouping, but the datetime doesn't let me perform any functions that I understand, other than count() and that's not that useful to me.  I have a list of the UniqueCallID and I think I want a for loop for each UniqueCallID in that list, but I don't know what comes IN the for loop.

I want to compare the last two rows of each UniqueCallID group and act if they're far apart in time.

Here's an idea of what the data looks like.

```
data={'UniqueCallID':[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3,3], 'LeaveTime': ['2019-06-26 15:45:32','2019-06-26 15:45:34','2019-06-26 15:45:37','2019-06-27 04:30:33','2019-06-05 07:32:14','2019-06-05 07:33:16','2019-06-05 11:06:22','2019-06-21 15:42:37','2019-06-22 18:30:42']}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

I want Index value 3's LeaveTime to read as 2019-06-26 15:45:37, the same as Index value 2.  The real index value ties back to the original dataframe and I think I would plan to merge the two, overwriting the rows that are targeted by index.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
df.groupby("UniqueCallID").apply(my_func,"delta")
```

where delta is the difference x in time (60 minutes or 1 hour) from first hung-up;

```
delta = pd.Timedelta("60min")
```

I would write my_func like this:

```
def my_func(grouped,delta):
  first_leave_time = grouped["LeaveTime"].min()
  last_acceptable_leave_time = grouped.loc[grouped.LeaveTime<=first_leave_time+delta,"LeaveTime"].max()
  grouped.loc[grouped.LeaveTime>first_leave_time+delta,"LeaveTime"]=last_acceptable_leave_time
  return grouped
```

This is what you get:

```
#Output
    UniqueCallID           LeaveTime
0         1         2019-06-26 15:45:32
1         1         2019-06-26 15:45:32
2         1         2019-06-26 15:45:32
3         1         2019-06-26 15:45:32
4         2         2019-06-05 07:32:14
5         2         2019-06-05 07:32:14
6         2         2019-06-05 07:32:14
7         3         2019-06-21 15:42:37
8         3         2019-06-21 15:42:37
```

Comment: This is very nice. Thank you so much.  A question: where does grouped come from? Is it the original dataframe slice, or is it an intermediary step, something like groupby UniqueCallID without applying the function?

What I'm not sure I follow is how does this iterate through each UniqueCallId, which it obviously does, but how?

Comment: A call "grouped" the group of items in the same category: all items with callID=1 are grouped toghether. So for each of this groups you apply what's written inside my_func: so you take the min, than you locate the last_acceptable etc... and at the end you return your modify grouped. Pandas knows where to put it. MMMh, I saw a nice depiction of this somewhere... maybe it was the on the book Pandas Cookbook.